# Issue in building docker image using habitus

Tags: docker, habitus

I am trying to build Docker image using Habitus, so that I can securely pass build time secrets (github ssh keys) to docker.

My Habitus build file:

```
build:
  version: 2016-03-14
  steps:
    builder:
      name: search/poirot
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      secrets:
        id_rsa:
          type: file
          value: _env(HOME)/.ssh/id_rsa
      cleanup:
        commands:
          - rm -rf /root/.ssh/
```

I have the latest Docker for Mac installed on my machine. I am running this command to build:

> sudo ./habitus
>   --certs=$HOME/.docker/machine/certs/ --host=192.168.99.100:59124

I am using the IP and port from "~/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json"

```
Content:
    "Driver": {
        "IPAddress": "192.168.99.100",
        "MachineName": "default",
        "SSHUser": "docker",
        "SSHPort": 59124,
        "SSHKeyPath": "/Users/shiladityamandal/.docker/machine/machines/default/id_rsa",
        "StorePath": "/Users/shiladityamandal/.docker/machine",
        "SwarmMaster": false,
        "SwarmHost": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376",
        "SwarmDiscovery": "",
        "VBoxManager": {},
        "HostInterfaces": {},
        "CPU": 1,
        "Memory": 2048,
        "DiskSize": 20000,
        "NatNicType": "82540EM",
        "Boot2DockerURL": "",
        "Boot2DockerImportVM": "",
        "HostDNSResolver": false,
        "HostOnlyCIDR": "192.168.99.1/24",
        "HostOnlyNicType": "82540EM",
        "HostOnlyPromiscMode": "deny",
        "NoShare": false,
        "DNSProxy": true,
        "NoVTXCheck": false
    },
```

I keep getting the following error during build:

> Build for step test/test failed due to Post
>   https://192.168.99.100:59124/build?dockerfile=Dockerfile.generated&rm=1&t=search%2Fservice:
>   dial tcp 192.168.99.100:59124: i/o timeout

What am I doing wrong?

I was following this process- https://dzone.com/articles/using-ssh-private-keys-securely-in-docker-build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself. Had to connect to 192.168.99.100:2376